# Why is a metric?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I have a question about tensors and metrics:

Let $M=\{(t,x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^4: t>-1 \}$ and let $g=(1+t)dtdx+dy^2+dz^2$

Show that g is a metric on $M$.

I did the next, I have the basis $\{ \partial_t , \partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z\}$, then, $g=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1+t  &0  & 0\\ 
0 &  0& 0 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$.

And this matrix is not symmetric! So g is not a metric.

Where is my mistake?

Thanks a lot!

---

EDIT: Which is it's index?
I don't know it...

I think that this basis 
$\{ \partial_t - \partial_x,\partial_t + \partial_x,\partial_y,\partial_z\}$
is ortonormal and has only one temporal vector, so it index is 1
Thanks!!

Comment: Note that $dtdx$ is a common shorthand for $(dtdx+dxdt)/2$.

Comment: I didn't know that!!. Then it's trivial...

Comment: It's perhaps less potentially confusing to say that $dt\,dx$ is a common shorthand for $\frac{1}{2}(dt \otimes dx + dx \otimes dt)$.

Comment: @Travis Yes, I knew that notation, but the other not, thanks

Answer (score 4):

As $dtdx =\frac{dtdx+dxdt}{2}$, then $g=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &(1+t)/2  &0  & 0\\ 
(1+t)/2 &  0& 0 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$, so $g$ is symmetric and it has inverse. Then, $g$ is a metric on $M$